# Resource id #6 error, Not sure how to fix it

Tags: php, sql

I keep getting a 'Resource id # 6' failure when submitting a script on my website. The code I'm using is the same type of code I use for registering for the website and that works but this script doesn't work at all. What my code does is send a booking request with the fields as shown to the database. I keep getting a Resource id#6 error , and I've googled what that is but I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. I am a beginner at php , so any tips on whats to look for to avoid a resource id # 6 error would be a lot of help

```
<?php
//$pattern="/^.+@.+/.com/";

//error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $Name_of_Person = $_POST['Name_of_Person'];
    $Name_of_Group = $_POST['Name_of_Group'];
    $room = $_POST['room'];
    $How_Many_People = $_POST['How_Many_People'];
    $Date_of_Booking = $_POST['Date_of_Booking'];
    $End_time = $_POST['End_time'];
    $Purpose = $_POST['Purpose'];
    $Contact_Number = $_POST['Contact_Number'];
    $Contact_Email = $_POST['Contact_Email'];
    $Alcohol = $_POST['Alcohol'];
    $Security = $_POST['Security'];
    $Projector = $_POST['Projector'];
    $Extra_Chairs = $_POST['Extra_Chairs'];
    $Extra_Info = $_POST['Extra_Info'];
    $Activated = '0';

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','test123') or die("couldn't connect");
    mysql_select_db('bookerdb') or die("couldn't connect to DB");


        //if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){//(preg_match($pattern, $_POST['Contact_Email'])){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `booking_table` WHERE Date_of_Booking='".$Date_of_Booking."' AND room='".$room."'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            echo $query;
            if($numrows==0){
                $sql="INSERT INTO `booking_table` (Name_of_Person,Name_of_Group,room,How_Many_People,Date_of_Booking,End_time,Purpose,Contact_Number,Contact_Email,Alcohol,Security,Projector,Extra_Chairs,Extra_Info, Activated) VALUES ('$Name_of_Person','$Name_of_Group','$room','$How_Many_People','$Date_of_Booking','$End_time','$Purpose','$Contact_Number','$Alcohol','$Security','$Projector','$Extra_Chairs','$Extra_Info',$Activated)";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                if($result){
                    echo "Sent to be approved";
                    $redirect_page = '../ASC.php';
                    $redirect = true;
                    if($redirect==true){
                        header('Location: ' .$redirect_page);
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "Failed";
                }
            }else{
                echo"There is already a requested booking on that date & time";
                $redirect_page = '../EAR.php';
                $redirect = true;
                if($redirect==true){
                    header('Location: ' .$redirect_page);
                }
            }
        /*}else{
            echo "error";
            $redirect_page = '../EWF.php';
            $redirect = true;
            if($redirect==true){
                header('Location: ' .$redirect_page);
            }
        }*/
}

?>
```

Comment: What line are you getting it on?

Comment: I removed the echo query; thank you ,that removed the resource error but the script is still failing , but thats something clearly on my side

Comment: @AndrewO'Neill: what does _still failing_ means? What it do and what it should do?

Comment: actually i have another query , its about $Activated = '0' and how i insert it into the table , is that a valid way of doing it?

Comment: failing as in its not completing the 'INSERT' statement into my database, for some reason its failing at the $result condition of the loop

Comment: @AndrewO'Neill: I've updated my answer below, you forgot to insert email value in your second query.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your second SQL query. You try to insert 14 values into 15 columns (in values you forgot `$Contact_Email`).

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `booking_table` (Name_of_Person,Name_of_Group,room,How_Many_People,Date_of_Booking,End_time,Purpose,Contact_Number,Contact_Email,Alcohol,Security,Projector,Extra_Chairs,Extra_Info, Activated) VALUES ('$Name_of_Person','$Name_of_Group','$room','$How_Many_People','$Date_of_Booking','$End_time','$Purpose','$Contact_Number','$Contact_Email','$Alcohol','$Security','$Projector','$Extra_Chairs','$Extra_Info',$Activated)";
```

Than remove `echo $query` from your code, line 30.

In `$query` isn't query, but mysql result object. You can't work with that by this way, you can't echo it.

Comment: ugh , its always the little things , thank you so much for clearing my head ache

Comment: @AndrewO'Neill: try to better indent your code, you could find this mistake by yourself. This 'inline' style isn't the right one.